# Accessing SharePoint via Drupal using CMIS Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cmis

I'm trying to set up the CMIS Module (7.x-1.6) in Drupal 7 (hosted on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) to access our SharePoint instance.

I keep getting a 401 HTTP error. From what I understand, this is because our SharePoint instance uses NTLM (when I access the SharePoint CMIS WSDL using wget with --user and --password then I get two 401 responses followed by a successful 200 response).

Can anyone give me walk-through instructions on how to configure the Drupal CMIS module. I've been looking at the CMIS Headerswing Transport part of the CMIS module, but I'm not sure how to use it (I've never dealt with NTLM before).

Comment: I can't comment on the Drupal CMIS Module, but I have experience with CMIS and SharePoint. Don't use NTLM! You will run into several issues. Configure SharePoint to accept basic authentictaion.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an option - the SharePoint instance is used across the entire global company I work for, and I very much doubt they'll reconfigure it just for this.

Comment: If you try to connect to SharePoint 2013, you probably need NTLMv2 support in PHP/libcurl. Otherwise, your authentication attempts will never be successful.